# how to get response with message,error, status in django rest framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

HI Everyone i am creating api using drf but i want response with different formet, below i have mention my current response and expected response.how can achieve me my expected api response formet.

**views.py**

```
class TeamlistViewset(viewsets.ViewSet):
    def list (self,request):
        team=Team.objects.all()
        serializer=TeamSerializer(team,many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

**api response**

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Deadly Shark"
    }
]
```

**expected api response**

```
{
    "message": "list retrieval",
    "error": false,
    "code": 200,
    "results": {
        "totalItems": 1,
        "pageData": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "Deadly Shark"
                
            }
        ],
        "totalPages": null,
        "currentPage": 0
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

this is solution

```
class DriverlistViewset(viewsets.ViewSet):
    # permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)

    def list (self,request):
        team=Team.objects.all()
        serializer=TeamSerializer(team,many=True)
        # headers=self.get_success_headers(serializer.data)
        try:
            return Response({'message':'sucess','error':False,'code':200,'result':{'totalItems':len(serializer.data),'items':serializer.data,'totalPages':'null','currentPage':0}},status=HTTP_200_OK)
        except Exception as e:
            return Response({'message':'fail','error':True,'code':500,'result':{'totalItems':0,'items':[],'totalPages':0,'currentPage':0}})
```

Comment: Is this a solution for your question, or a clarification? If it's a solution, please edit the answer to say so, if it's a clarification, please edit it into the question.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late but you can do it like this

```
class TeamlistViewset(viewsets.ViewSet):
    def list (self,request):
        team=Team.objects.all()
        serializer=TeamSerializer(team,many=True)
        response = {
           "message": "list retrieval",
           "error": False,
           "code": 200,
           "results": serializer.data
        }
        return Response(response, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

If you get type error that you cannot send data of Type Team i.e. your model, then serialize the data you receive first. Also it is better to add status code besides the response such as in the last line of the above code and not inside the response dictionary.